# interp1 returns NaN for last value in x range

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a question about the [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function in MATLAB. Let `x` be in the range [1, 1024]. However, the following:

```
yi = interp1(x, y, 1024);
```

returns `NaN`.

I've checked my program several times and nothing seems wrong but the result is still weird to me. I'd be thankful if anyone could help.

Comment: Can you post your `x` and `y` vectors? Are there repeated `x` values? Are they monotonically increasing?

Comment: Does x has the value "1024", or ends at lower value? interp can't interolate outside the range of x, unless specific methods are chosen.

Comment: @Dan yes, x is monotonically increasing. x= 1.0e+003 *[0.0010 0.0030 0.0050 .. 1.0240]  by the way, x has 638 elements. y is not monotonic. what I wanna get are values yi for xi= 1,2,3,..,1024

Comment: x = 1.0e+003 * [0.0010 0.0030 0.0050] == [1 3 5].. see shai's comment

Comment: @Adiel yes, x ends at 1024.

Comment: if the last value of x is 1024, then what's the last value of y?

Comment: Can you should how you calculate `x`? I reckon that maybe your x is missing 1024 due to a precision error so like it has 1023.999999999 for example. What does `sum(x==1024)` give you?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that you're not getting to 1024 but rather some value just less like 1023.999999999945435

Try out this very contrived example:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
interp1(x, y, 10) %This works, returns 10
```

Now try

```
x = 1:0.99999999768768765:10 %note x(end) will give you 10.0000, very deceptive because sum(x == 10 ) gives 0
interp(x, y, 10) %Returns NaN
```

So although my example is very contrived, sometimes it could happen that due to precision errors even though the series you specified should get exactly to 1024 it doesn't because of the truncation of representing nice looking decimal number in binary where they no longer look nice.

If this is your issue then either round off `x` to the appropriate precision or else you could specify extrapolation in the `interp1` options but I would think rounding is better because it will stop other unexpected precision issue down the line.

Answer (score 2):

You must verify that the value `1024` exists in your input `x`.

For example

```
>> x = 1: 2 : 1024;
```

seems like it contains 1024, but it does NOT!

```
>> x

   1 3 5 ... 1019 1021 1023
```

No 1024!

If you want to ensure that 1024 is indeed in `x`, you can use `linspace`:

```
>> x = linspace( 1, 1024, 512 ); % same number of elements as before, but now 1024 is included!
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could specify extrapolation - `yi = interp1(x,y,1024,method,'extrap');`

Answer (score -1):

To look whether x contains 1024 (or larger), you could use:
    any(x>=1024)