# Matlab interp1 gives last row as NaN

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, interpolation, nan

I have a problem similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341927/interp1-returns-nan-for-last-value-in-x-range). However, it doesn't seem that there is a resolution.

My problem is as such: I need to import some files, for example, 5. There are 20 columns in each file, but the number of lines are varied. Column 1 is time in terms of crank-angle degrees, and the rest are data.

So my code first imports all of the files, finds the file with the most number of rows, then creates a multidimensional array with that many rows. The timing is in engine cycles so, I would then remove lines from the imported file that go beyond a whole engine cycle.  This way, I always have data in terms of X whole engine cycles. Then I would just interpolate the data to the pre-allocated array to have a giant multi-dimensional array for the 5 data files.

However, this seems to always result in the last row of every column of every page being filled with NaNs. Please have a look at the code below. I can't see where I'm doing wrong. Oh, and by the way, as I have been screwed over before, this is NOT homework.

```
maxlines = 0;
maxcycle = 999;
for i = 1:1
    filename = sprintf('C:\\Directory\\%s\\file.out',folder{i});
    file = filelines(filename); % Import file clean
    lines = size(file,1); % Find number of lines of file
    if lines > maxlines
        maxlines = lines; % If number of lines in this file is the most, save it
    end
    lastCAD = file(end,1); % Add simstart to shift the start of the cycle to 0 CAD
    lastcycle = fix((lastCAD-simstart)./cycle); % Find number of whole engine cycles
    if lastcycle < maxcycle
        maxcycle = lastcycle; % Find lowest number of whole engine cycles amongst all designs
    end
    cols = size(file,2); % Find number of columns in files
end

lastcycleCAD = maxcycle.*cycle+simstart; % Define last CAD of whole cycle that can be used for analysis

% Import files
thermo = zeros(maxlines,cols,designs); % Initialize array to proper size
xq = linspace(simstart,lastcycleCAD,maxlines); % Define the CAD degrees
for i = 1:designs
    filename = sprintf('C:\\Directory\\%s\\file.out',folder{i});
    file = importthermo(filename, 6, inf); % Import the file clean
    [~,lastcycleindex] = min(abs(file(:,1)-lastcycleCAD)); % Find index of end of last whole cycle
    file = file(1:lastcycleindex,:); % Remove all CAD after that
    thermo(:,1,i) = xq;
    for j = 2:17
        thermo(:,j,i) = interp1(file(:,1),file(:,j),xq);
    end
    sprintf('file from folder %s imported OK',folder{i})
end

thermo(end,:,:) = []; % Remove NaN row
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sampling out of the range? if so, you need to tell `interp1` that you want extrapolation

```
 interp1(file(:,1),file(:,j),xq,'linear','extrap');
```

Comment: Do you think it might be happening when I chop off the 'excess' data after the whole engine cycles? Like maybe instead of a time of 1000.00, it might be a time of 1000.04, so that extra 0.04 results in the NaN?

Ander, you beautiful man! I just tried the extrapolation. That's the solutiion!

Comment: @user3654549 :D. Yes, it is likely that the reason is numerical inaccuracies.  Even 1000.0000000001 will make that NaN appear. If you know that this will be the only case (you will not give 2000 accidentally) then this method is great. Else, consider having a check before interpolating, as extrapolation very far from the values will result in ugly numbers.